# Stuck in cs50 pset3 frequency

Tags: cs50

I'm through with duration and is_rest but can't seem to understand what's wrong with my frequency code. 
I've basically is done three steps; 1) Determined by strlen to differentiate accidentals and normal. 2) Determined the piano key (first letter). 3) Then determined the octave and followed through. I repeated this over for all 7 letters for an octave.
Now when I run the program I get the same answer for all whether accidentals or normal i.e. for **A4 and A6 it returns the same value of -2147483648**.
I've spent a lot of time to solve it but to no avail. Can someone please go through my code and tell me what's wrong.

```
int frequency(string note)
{
int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, n, o, p, q, r;

double freq = 440;
// TODO
 //if note is XY
if (strlen (note) == 2)
{
   if (note[0] == 'A')
   {
       a = note[1];
       if (a < 4)
       {
           return round  ( freq / pow(2,(4 - a)));
       }
       if (a > 4)
       {
           return round ( freq *  pow(2, (a - 4)));
       }

       else if (a == 4)
       {
           return 440;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem starts here `a = note[1];`. Remember, `note[1]` is the *ascii representation* of the octave. Recall from pset2 how to "convert" a letter into it's "alphabetic index". This is analagous. ([ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference)

"4" in ascii is 52. So this `pow(2, (a - 4));` calculates a really, really, really big number that effectively "blows precision" (since the function returns a int).

That may not be the only problem in the function, but correcting it will get things moving along. It might be time to get familiar and comfortable with debug50.